# Is it possible to use Mean Shift Clustering for Text documents?

Tags: nlp, cluster-analysis, text-processing, document-classification, mean-shift

In resources which I read about Mean Shift, it's said that it's mainly used for image processing or visual data. Can't one use it for text clustering? Isn't it optimum for this purpose or what?!

I would be thankful if you provide me a link to a Shift Mean based code (Any programming language.)

Answer (score 1):

Mean shift is much too expensive for this.

Also, means do not work well for text.